# What does calve exactly mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

From the Cambridge dictionary "calve" means:

> Calve: When a cow calves, it gives birth to a calf (= a young cow):

But I've read somewhere that:

> Humans have encroached on open seas and eradicated **calving areas** of
> giant marine animals.

Is the phrase **"calving areas"** used correctly in this sentence? According to the dictionary, **calve means giving birth to a calf**, but in this sentence it talks about whales.

Do all mammals calve, or only cows calve?

Comment: There are other large marine animals so how do we know this is about whales?

Comment: @mdewey: Other large marine mammals, such as walruses, also have calves: https://www.livescience.com/27442-walrus-facts.html  Other marine animals usually don't give live birth.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Do all mammals calve, or only cows calve?

Neither.

The term "calve" was first used of cows, but it has long been used of whales giving birth, and a young whale is called a "calf". The term might be used for a few other animals, but is not used for most mammals. Dogs "whelp", horses "foal", and sheep "drop a lamb" but the season when they do so is "lambing time". Cats, foxes, rodents, and some others are said to "litter". I think that "whelp" is also used of wolves.

In all these cases "give birth" may be used instead.

The verb "calve" is also used when an iceberg breaks off from the parent glacier, as by analogy the iceberg is "born". "Calve" is also used in some other cases where a smaller thing breaks off from a larger. I believe it is sometimes used of comets, for example.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/calve) defines the verb "calve" as:

> verb (used without object), calved, calv·ing.

> - to give birth to a calf:
>   -- *The cow is expected to calve tomorrow.*

> - (of a glacier, an iceberg,> etc.) to break up or splinter so as to produce a detached piece.

> verb (used with object), calved, calv·ing.

> - to give birth to (a calf).

> - (of a > glacier, an iceberg, etc.) to break off or detach (a piece):

> -- *The > glacier calved an iceberg.*

There is a very similar definition from [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=calve) and one from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/calve) and one from [Oxford/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/calve)

I think this verb should **not** be used in general for "to give birth to" but only with [certain specific kinds of animals](https://www.babyanimalprints.com/blogs/news/calves-arent-just-baby-cows) (cows, whales, elephants, etc) and with a few kinds of objects where a smaller fragment breaks off of a larger, mostly n glaciers and things thought to act in a way similar way to glaciers.

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+birth+to%2C+calve%2C+spawn&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgive%20birth%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspawn%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgive%20birth%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspawn%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "calve" is significantly less common than "give birth to" or spawn". [This one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=giving+birth+to%2Ccalving%2Cspawning&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiving%20birth%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspawning%3B%2Cc0) shows similar results for the gerund forms.

Comment: What is "neither" meant to be addressing?

Comment: @T.J.L. Neither is the response to the final question "Do all mammals calve, or only cows calve?". That is, the term does not apply only to cows, but does not apply to all mammals either.

Comment: Nice points, but I think your summary is wrong - "calving" is clearly being used here (and elsewhere) to refer to _any_ non-specific birthing event. It's wrong to use it of certain specific species, but not as a generalisation.

Comment: @Mike Brockington  I don't think so. Dictionary defs do not support this as appropriate for any birthing event in general. See the edited answer for one example.

Comment: @MikeBrockington "Large marine mammals" giving birth in the open sea is pretty specific. There aren't many marine mammals to begin with. Some of them are small (otters) or give birth on land (polar bears, seals). All of the ones that can be described as large and give birth in the open water also have the specific word calf for their young. Specifically, whales, dolphins, and manatees.

Comment: @MikeBrockington No, not really. If the young are called calves, then giving birth is called ‘calving’. Young cetaceans (like most marine mammals) are called calves, ergo whales ‘calve’ instead of giving birth (as do dolphins, though that confuses people a bit because they associate ‘calve’ with ‘young bovid’ and thus ‘young large animal’).

Comment: Dictionaries generally have limited space, so rarely cover all possible options. @AustinHemmelgarn  Yes really. The example the OP provided is far from unique - 'calving' appears to be the commonest current colloquialism for the act of giving birth, in general. Arguably, that is precisely why it is also used for icebergs.

Comment: @MikeBrockington "Spawning" is used much more commonly than "calving".

Comment: @MikeBrockington Dictionaries may not cover everything, but when a word is commonly used in a broad general sense, particularly when it is "the commonest current colloquialism " for an act, they mention it. Can you cite several published uses of "calve" meaning "to give birth" in a general sense not referring to any of the specified mammals nor to any of the limited class of objects which others here have said use that verb?

Comment: @MikeBrockington See the Ngrams recently added to the answer.

Comment: @MikeBrockington good luck with telling your wife "congratulations on calving us another kid". Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Cetaceans, manatees etc. calve calves, but seals don't - they pup pups.  And I doubt even @MikeBrockington would be very happy to say a mare calves a foal (no one else does, all Google hits are along the lines of "some calves, a foal, and a piglet")

Comment: @ChrisH, I was not aware that "pup" is a verb... but [wiktionary says it is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pup#Verb), so okay. I would have expected that seals *[whelp](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whelp)* pups, which also seems to be acceptable. Anyway, welcome to the wonderfully confusing world of animal husbandry jargon! It's much like those cultures with sixty words for "snow"...

Comment: @Matthew "whelp" is also good - as both verb and noun, overlapping (IMO) with "pup" and "cub" - the latter not normally being used as a verb

Comment: @SandyChapman (and others) I specifically said that i was talking about giving birth "in general" (as does the example the OP provided) - not about specific cases/species.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  That ngram appears to me to show that, while less common than the more formal "give birth",  "calving" is in common enough usage.

Answer (score 18):

It's correctly used:

[American Heritage Dictionary "calf"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=calf)

> 1.a. A young cow or bull.
> b. One of the young of **certain other mammals, such as moose, elephants, or whales**.

[emphasis added]

Interestingly, even glaciers are said to calve:
(from the same dictionary)
3. A large floating chunk of ice split off from a glacier, iceberg, or floe.

Comment: The pattern seems to be that relatively large animals have calves (moose being one of the largest in the deer family). And icebergs and glaciers are large structures of ice.

Comment: @Barmar: I think it's not so much large, as large and not familiar enough to have a special word in English.  E.g. horses have foals, deer have fawns, but elephants, hippos, and so on have calves.  Likewise unfamiliar small animals are often said to have pups.

Comment: @Barmar The pattern is that mammals for which the young are known as calves ‘calve’. This includes cetaceans (including the little ones), pinnipeds, sirenians, pachyderms, and a large selection of ungulates (including bovids, rhinoceri, hippopotami, most cervids, and most tylopods, as well as a few others I’m probably missing)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I think the correlation between the noun and verb is too obvious to even mention.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: The comment that you're replying to says "have calves", not "calve".

Comment: The usage in question was over the verb, not the noun. This answer doesn't reflect that.